# A system to tune sympathetic strings for Western music

Tags: chords, scales, tuning, effects-pedal

I've just got an EHX Ravish pedal and so I'm exploring the sympathetic string function.

For standard Western, meantone temperament: diatonic or modal, major or minor melodies what are good rules for choosing sympathetic strings?   I'm guessing that an octave above and below the roots would be a good start.  What other strings should I choose to bring out the harmonic space?  Fifths too strong?  Thirds a problem?

Comment: “For Western music” is a bit too unspecific here. What rough direction are you aiming at, sound-wise? The sympathetic strings in a Hardanger fiddle have a pretty different effect from the open strings in a piano with held pedal, or the bordun strings of a theorbo.

Comment: @leftaroundabout well the hardanger is just temperament but I'm interested in all the possibilities tbh.